# Creating heat map based on attribute from another layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, geometry, heat-map

I have a layer showing different trails in a nature areal. For each trail, there is an attribute with the usage of the trail (no. of people passing a trail counter). I now want to create a new layer as a heat map, based on the attribute. How do I do that?

I only know how to do in the original trail-layer, working with the symbology. But I want the heat map to be showed as a separate layer, since it's easier to work with the original trail-layer. So, the heat map should automatically load the geometry and attributes from the original trail-layer.

Comment: Duplicate your layer via `RMC > Duplicate Layer`. When applying a change to the original layer the duplicated one will be updated also

Comment: Is it realy that easy. Thanks :-)

Comment: Does it solve your problem? May I put as a valid answer to this question?

Comment: Yes, it worked fine. Ecxactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate your layer via `RMC > Duplicate Layer`.

[image: duplicate]

When applying a change to the original layer
[image: before]

also the duplicated one will be updated
[image: after]